# Updating an intent that starts an activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an intent that starts an activity that shows an `alert dialog` when a new message comes in from `GCM (Google Cloud Messenger)`. The Dialog shows the number of unread messages but if a new message comes in after one was already displayed and you have not viewed the previous one the dialog should update the unread count to reflect the number of new/unread messages.

However the intent does not update the dialog if the activity with the dialog is active so how can I update it since I cant call dismiss on the dialog?

the intent if there is a new message

```
if((incMsgs + dlMsgs) > 0 && !mMsgType.equals("Reg")){
                edit.putBoolean(Preferences.NEW_ALERT, true).commit();
                priorityMsgs = true;
                Intent i = new Intent(this,NotificationDialog.class);
                i.putExtra("incidents", incMsgs);
                i.putExtra("dlMessages", dlMsgs);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to override [OnNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) of the activity. And in this update the Ui elements. For this to work your activity launchMode needs to be singleTop

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my issue by adding this on my intent:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Maybe this can help you too.